# How to make lines to be more guided in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, line

Does anyone how to make lines to be more guided in unity? Guided as in how you use a real life ruler where the drawn lines is not suppose to be straight and the direction of the line or the end point of the line is affected by how you place the ruler. Currently my code, im able to draw lines and collide with the ruler but the lines are more of a freehand drawing. So how do i make it like what i say earlier on.
Heres my code for the line properties script.

```
    void Update()
    { 
    this.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().useGravity = false;
    this.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().constraints = 
    RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationX | 
    RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationZ | 
    RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionY | 
    RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionZ;
}

public void OnCollisionStay(Collision col)
{       
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Ruler") 
    {
        if (LockPosX == false && LockPosY == false)
        {
            Debug.Log ("Collision with Ruler");
            //line.SetPosition(1 , newPosititon);
            //newPosititon.y = col.transform.position.y;
            //newPosititon.z = 0;
            LockPosY = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Heres my code for spawning the line/drawing the line:

```
 void Update ()
{
  if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        if (line == null) 
        {
            createLine ();

            mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
            mousePos.z = 0;
            line.SetPosition (0, mousePos);

            startPos = mousePos;
        }
    }
    else if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && line)
    {
        mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        mousePos.z = 0;
        line.SetPosition(1,mousePos);
        endPos = mousePos;
        addColliderToLine ();
        line = null;
        currLines++;
    }
    else if(Input.GetMouseButton(0) && line)
    {
        mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        mousePos.z = 0;
        line.SetPosition(1, mousePos);
    }
}

public void createLine()
{
    line = new GameObject("Line"+currLines).AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
    line.material =  material;
    line.tag = "DrawnLines";
    line.SetVertexCount(2);
    line.SetWidth(0.15f,0.15f);
    line.useWorldSpace = true;

}

private void addColliderToLine()
{
    BoxCollider col = new GameObject("Collider").AddComponent<BoxCollider> ();
    col.transform.parent = line.transform; 
    float lineLength = Vector3.Distance (startPos, endPos); 
    col.size = new Vector3 (lineLength, 1.0f, 5f); 
    Vector3 midPoint = (startPos + endPos)/2;
    col.transform.position = midPoint; 
    float angle = (Mathf.Abs (startPos.y - endPos.y) / Mathf.Abs (startPos.x - endPos.x));
    if((startPos.y<endPos.y && startPos.x>endPos.x) || (endPos.y<startPos.y && endPos.x>startPos.x))
    {
        angle*=-1;
    }
    angle = Mathf.Rad2Deg * Mathf.Atan (angle);
    col.transform.Rotate (0, 0, angle);
    col.gameObject.AddComponent<LineProperties> ();
    col.gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody> ();
}
```

Comment: I don't get what you are asking. Can you please try to describe the actual and the wished behavior a bit further?

Comment: The wished behaviour is that the users can use a gameobject which is a ruler (the one that you use for maths) to draw straight lines instead of a free hand drawing.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want to do is snap the position of the user's mouse input to the line created by ruler. If this is the case, you could simply use a simple function to accomplish this before setting the line's position.

```
//This function returns a point which is a projection from a point to a line.
//The line is regarded infinite. If the line is finite, use ProjectPointOnLineSegment() instead.
public static Vector3 ProjectPointOnLine(Vector3 linePoint, Vector3 lineVec, Vector3 point)
{

    //get vector from point on line to point in space
    Vector3 linePointToPoint = point - linePoint;

    float t = Vector3.Dot(linePointToPoint, lineVec);

    return linePoint + lineVec * t;
}
```

For the first argument - `linePoint` - you would pass in some point along the ruler's edge. If the ruler gameObject's pivot is along this edge, you can just use the ruler's position. The second argument - `lineVec` - is the direction vector created by the ruler. Depending on how the ruler's gameObject is oriented, this could be as simple as `ruler.transform.forward`. Finally, for the third argument, you would pass in `Input.mousePosition`. If you do not want their input to be snapped to the ruler, but where they started, you would then pass in your `Input.mousePosition` to the first parameter as well. This will snap it to a line following the same direction as the ruler, but the line will start where their input started.

So your `void Update()` method becomes:

```
void Update ()
{
  if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        if (line == null) 
        {
            createLine ();

            mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (ProjectPointOnLine(Input.mousePosition, ruler.transform.forward, Input.mousePosition));
            mousePos.z = 0;
            line.SetPosition (0, mousePos);

            startPos = mousePos;
        }
    }
    else if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && line)
    {
        mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(ProjectPointOnLine(Input.mousePosition, ruler.transform.forward, Input.mousePosition));
        mousePos.z = 0;
        line.SetPosition(1,mousePos);
        endPos = mousePos;
        addColliderToLine ();
        line = null;
        currLines++;
    }
    else if(Input.GetMouseButton(0) && line)
    {
        mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(ProjectPointOnLine(Input.mousePosition, ruler.transform.forward, Input.mousePosition));
        mousePos.z = 0;
        line.SetPosition(1, mousePos);
    }
}
```

**Edit**

If you need a method to retrieve all of the lines with a specific tag - such as `DrawnLines` which you use in the `createLines()` method, you can do something like the following

```
private void UpdateLines()
{
    GameObject[] drawnLineGameObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("DrawnLines");
    foreach (var lineObject in drawnLineGameObjects)
    {
        LineRenderer drawnLine = lineObject.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

        if (drawnLine != null)
        {
            // Do stuff to your Line Renderer Here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: oh hmm, currently im trying to use your code for void update but how do i find a gameobject / line renderer that will be spawn in the scene? Currently i have tried using gameobject.findgameobjectwithtag but it didnt work out.

Comment: You could use the FindObjectOfType<> call.

`LineRenderer line = FindObjectOfType<LineRenderer>()`

Comment: Ah, is there any way that i can specify target a set of lines or lines with specify tag?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include an example of fetching all game objects with a tag.